# Companion matrix complexity

Tags: matrix, complexity-theory

I know this is more a complexity theory question than a programming question, hope I'm not doing the wrong thing writing here, apologize me if it's the wrong place but I hope someone of you have the answer. And it's even someway programmin related by being a complexity theory qestion.

I'm studying Linear Recurring Sequences, and I read that in order to obtain the n-th value of the sequence it popped out that you need to get some power of a companion matrix, I was wondering if there's a known algorithm to get powers of this kind of matrix in a fast way..

I can't give coding example, but I shall try to get you some more explanation:

Homogeneous Linear Recurring Sequence of k-th order:
 
s(n+k)=a(k-1)s(n+k-1)+a(k-2)s(n+k-2)+...+a(0) 
for n=0,1,.. where s(i) is the i-th value of the sequence, and the a(i) are coefficients in an Algebraic Field.

A is the companion matrix of the above sequence if it's: 
( 0 0 0 0 ... 0 a(0) )
( 1 0 0 0 ... 0 a(1) )
( 0 1 0 0 ... 0 a(2) )
( .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..)
( 0 0 0 0 ... 1 a(k-1) )
Moreover Theory states that for the state vectors of the sequence we have: 
 
s(n) = s(0)A^n for n=0,1,.. 
That's it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The usual strategy for finding powers of a matrix quickly is to diagonalise it (perform eigenvector decomposition):

A = P<sup>-1</sup> D P

where D is a diagonal matrix.  You can then raise A to the power n by calculating

A<sup>n</sup> = P<sup>-1</sup> D<sup>n</sup> P

where D<sup>n</sup> is fast to compute because it's a diagonal matrix, so you just take the powers of each element separately.

However not all matrices are diagonalisable -- I don't know if your companion matrix will be or not.  You might find [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) helpful in any case.

Comment: It's not always diagonalizable, only if the roots of the characteristic polynoials are distinct, anyway ok, it's  good, but I was wondering if there were some way to exploit the structure of the matrix, ty

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the `n`th power of a matrix `M` using `O(log n)` matrix products:

- if `n=0`, return `I`
- if `n` is even, compute `N=M`<sup>`n/2`</sup> and return `N*N`
- if `n` is odd, compute `N=M`<sup>`n-1`</sup> and return `M*N`

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't figure out how you can make it in O(log n), I think that each matrix multiplication is yet O(n^2) where n is the number of rows (supposin a square matrix), isn't so?

Comment: Oh ok, did'n read well :D it's O(log n) * cost of a matrix product, so it will be O(n^2 log n), right? Thank you, but I think this is not what I need, I was wondering for a kind of exploit of the special kind matrix...

Comment: Not exactly. Matrix product is (thought to be) harder than that, but the size of the matrix, say m×m, is completely unrelated to the exponent n, so it would be O(m^2.807 log n) with Strassen's algorithm or O(m^3 log n) with the naive algorithm.